# Which function in python equivalent to quantile type=1 in R?

Tags: python, r, numpy, math, quantile

I have a range of number like

```py
lista= [100, 200, 350, 700, 950, 275, 563]
```

In R I have function quantile like this:

```r
Cutoff= quantile(lista,0.36,na.rm = FALSE,names = FALSE, type = 1)
```

Is there any function that is equivalent in Python?
I read document python about quantile but there no option as type 1 in R.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html 
Check the method option for the correspondence with the types of R's quantile function.

Comment: Did the answer was helpful for you? you can accept it to let others know @ThanhTruyen

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use the `numpy.quantile` function, but the default is equivalent to `type=7` in R, as stated in the comments you can refer to [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html) in order to read more about it.

`numpy` does not provide an equivalent for `type=1` in R.

Using your dummy data, you can do something like this:

```py
import numpy as np

def quantileType1(array, q):
    sorted_array = np.sort(array)
    n = len(sorted_array)
    i = n * q
    if i.is_integer():
        return sorted_array[int(i)-1]
    else:
        j = int(i)
        return (1 - (i - j)) * sorted_array[j - 1] + (i - j) * sorted_array[j]

lista= [100, 200, 350, 700, 950, 275, 563]
Cutoff = quantileType1(lista, 0.36)
```

Using the `numpy.quantile` function can be done like so:

```py
cutoff = np.quantile(lista, 0.36, interpolation='lower')
```

> Possible `quantile` types are as follows (from the numpy docs):
> `[linear, lower, higher, nearest, midpoint, weighted, trapezoidal, mean, median]`